# How to simulate a gradle build script in junit test?

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am playing a little bit with my own gradle plugin (for gradle 6.5.1). Now I wrote a small test (implemented in java)  which is not working:

```
        Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build();
        ScriptHandler buildscript = project.getBuildscript();
        Action<? super MavenArtifactRepository> action = new Action<MavenArtifactRepository>() {
            @Override
            public void execute(MavenArtifactRepository mavenArtifactRepository) {
                mavenArtifactRepository.setUrl("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/");
            }
        };
        buildscript.getRepositories().maven(action);

        buildscript.getDependencies().add("classpath", "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.9.RELEASE");
        project.getPlugins().apply("java");
        project.getPlugins().apply("io.spring.dependency-management");
```

It says `Plugin with id 'io.spring.dependency-management' not found.` I thought that I copied the original from https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.spring.dependency-management

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.9.RELEASE"
  }
}

apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
```

But I guess thats not the case. :-) Any idea how to translate that snippet to java world?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply an other plugin in your test you need the other plugin on your classpath. So you have to add to the build file of your gradle-plugin and than its there.

In this case it means write the following to your build.gradle

`testImplementation "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.9.RELEASE"`